# how to pass password and username from servlet to other secure

Tags: java, servlets

I am using java servlet  with google app engine.
I need a secure way to pass a pass and user name from one  servlet   to other.
what is a good way?

thanks!

Comment: encrypt before sending the information.

Comment: after that do I need to do a hash?

Comment: depends on your requirement. I would do sha256 encryption of password and store that directly in the database. User name can be passed as it is. As best practice, you should not store clear text password anywhere.

Comment: So you need to pass it over the wire (e.g. HTTP) or are your servlets inside the same application? Is only transport security required or do you need 'more'?

Comment: Does the both servlets run in the same container? If so, why exactly do you need to pass that information? Are you familiar with the servlet API? Request/session attributes and so on?

Comment: yes the servlets run on the same  container. I think that the session isnt safe

Comment: I found this: http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Java/Password-Encryption-Rationale-and-Java-Example/

Comment: I think that you incorrectly think that the session data is exposed in public. I suggest to invest some more time in properly learning the Servlet API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data needs to be request scoped, just pass it as request attribute.

```
User user = new User(username, password);
request.setAttrubute("user", user);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/otherServletUrl").forward(request, response);
```

In the other servlet it's available as:

```
User user = (User) request.getAttribute("user");
// ...
```

If the data needs to be session scoped, just store it in the session scope. This also survives redirects.

```
User user = new User(username, password);
request.getSession().setAttrubute("user", user);
response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/otherServletUrl");
```

In the other servlet it's available as:

```
User user = (User) request.getSession().getAttribute("user");
// ...
```

There's absolutely no need to encrypt this information as it isn't exposed in public. The data is entirely stored in server memory. I only wonder how it's useful to pass passwords around. You usually keep them in the database which is been validated upon login and then only pass the user identifier around.

Answer (score -1):

this is a very good information to do that: http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Java/Password-Encryption-Rationale-and-Java-Example/